# How to move a matched id of mat files in different folder

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mv, cp, xargs

I have Matlab (.mat) files in a particular folder. In a text document, I have some IDs list marked as 0 and 1. First I need to match the IDs and separate the mat files that are marked as '1'.
For your reference, I detailed it below with a sample set.

For instance: Assume that I have these files in a folder

```
2424903_ (1)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
1905302 (2)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
1904802 (1)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
1902101_IYYANAR (1)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
```

Text File:

```
2424903 - 1
1905302 - 0
1904802 - 0
1902101 - 1
```

Expected result:

```
2424903_ (1)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
1902101_IYYANAR (1)_crop_vampire_3.1.2.mat
```

I need only these 2 files in a seperate folder.

I have tried below codes

```
$cat file.txt | xargs mv -t ./new folder
$xargs -a file.txt mv -t ./new folder
```

but I get errors like "No such file or directories"
Kindly suggest a code/method to separate those files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
  id_num=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  id_inc=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
  if [[ "$id_inc" == 1 ]]; then
    file=$(find -name "${id_num}*")
    mv "$file" -t './new folder'
    # echo "$file" # if you want to print the filename
  fi
done < file.txt
```

There is an issue with Xargs and filenames containing spaces. This solution instead runs through each line, checks if the last field is 1, and in this case moves the file to `new folder`.